# React/Redux : using data from Redux store during component's initial render() call

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am wondering how to make use of data in a Redux store during the initial render of a component.  I'm attempting to set the **name** attribute of a  component using data from MongoDB that is stored in an auth object in Redux.

```
<FontAwesome className="share-icon" name={this.props.auth.primaryAccount} />;
```

The **auth.primaryAccount** key will contain a string (either "google", "facebook", "github" or "twitter" and when this string populates as the name attribute in the  component, it will render the proper brand icon.

If I have a parent container  that is synced to the Redux store via the react-redux **Connect()** helper, where the auth object is made available to props via mapStateToProps, if  component is placed directly into a parent component's render() statement, ***this.props.auth.primaryAccount*** has a null value when the component intially renders. Placing *console.log(this.props.auth)* into the  component's **componentDidMount** method results in a **null** value, while placing  *console.log(this.props.auth)* into the **componentDidUpdate** method results in the expected **auth object** from Redux.

```
  render() {
      return (
       <div className="dashboardContainer">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <PanelContainer bordered={false} defaultActiveKey={["1"]}>
          <Panel header="PRIMARY ACCOUNT INFORMATION" key="1" showArrow={false}>
            <FontAwesome className="share-icon" name={this.props.auth.primaryAccount} />
          </Panel>
        </PanelContainer>
       </div>
      );
    }
```

The proper value for ***this.props.auth.primaryAccount*** isnt' made available from Redux until after the initial component mount/render. I'm assuming that is due to the async nature of the auth action creator's query to MongoDB to retrieve the auth object data.

I have been able to get around this by using a switch statement within a helper function that prevents the  component from rendering until the Redux data has been made available within **this.props** (below) however I'd hate to have to write helper functions for every line of JSX that references data stored in Redux.  What is the best way to utilized Redux data for component render?

```
  renderIcon() {
    switch (this.props.auth) {
      case null:
        return; 
      default:
        return <FontAwesome className="share-icon" name={this.props.auth.primaryAccount} />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dashboardContainer">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <PanelContainer bordered={false} defaultActiveKey={["1"]}>
          <Panel header="PRIMARY ACCOUNT INFORMATION" key="1" showArrow={false}>
            {this.renderIcon()}
          </Panel>
        </PanelContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common pattern to see checking for data in react projects.  People often use a different syntax than a switch statement though.  They often use a conditional shortcut like this:

```
renderIcon() {
    var auth = this.props.auth
    return auth && <FontAwesome className="share-icon" name={auth.primaryAccount} />;
}
```

Another version is with the ternary operator:

```
renderIcon() {
    var auth = this.props.auth
    return auth ? <FontAwesome className="share-icon" name={auth.primaryAccount} /> : null;
}
```

Comment: Ah!  So my mind was struggling against what is, in fact, the nature of the beast.  For some reason, I made the assumption that my comprehension of the React/Redux relationship was incomplete.  Thanks!